# You must load or assign this property before you can read it

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get the 'uniqueBody' from an email message but I get the above error. I only get this error when trying to read uniqueBody, just getting the body works fine

I've tried using the 'Load()' method but that hasn't worked..

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = exchange.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, filter, new ItemView(50));

            foreach (Item item in findResults)
            {                   
                EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange, item.Id);
                sB.Append("<strong>Email:</strong> " + message.From.Address.ToString() + "<BR />");
                sB.Append("<strong>Requestor:</strong> " + message.From.Name.ToString() + "<BR />");
                sB.Append("<strong>Subject:</strong> " + message.Subject.ToString() + "<BR />");
                sB.Append("<strong>Body:</strong> " + message.Body.ToString() + "<BR />");

                //message.Load();
                uniqueBody = message.UniqueBody.ToString(); //THIS BREAKS

<SNIP>
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e0de23e0-e4a4-4457-a0a5-1c6d8c438d0d/how-do-i-get-uniquebody-from-incoming-email-in-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Comment: per MS docs: "The UniqueBody element represents an HTML fragment or plain text which represents the unique body of this conversation." If I un-comment the message.Load(); line, it makes no difference I still get the same error

Comment: Sorry Chetan, saw your entry after I'd added mine :)  yes, that was the answer thaks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e0de23e0-e4a4-4457-a0a5-1c6d8c438d0d/how-do-i-get-uniquebody-from-incoming-email-in-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment][1] needed to create a property list and include the UniqueBody

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers